# In Android target sdk version 30 image from app specific directory is not shown in app

Tags: android, android-11, data-files, targetsdkversion

Added uses permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in AndroidManifest.xml, but still not showing.

Answer (score 0):

`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` won't work. Hence use something like the below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

Comment: I tried it but still image is not showing

Comment: Depends on how you are showing the picture. Please post the relevant code

Comment: In page image path is specified in src like:
'<img src =" .../Android/Data/com.myapp/files/images/imagename.png">'